# How to add a string-valued macro via qmake DEFINES?

Tags: c++, qt, macros, qmake

I'm trying to add a macro similar to `#define CPP_COMPILER_SETTING "g++ -std=c++1z"`

in the `.pro` file:

```
DEFINES += "CPP_COMPILER_SETTING=\\\"g++ \\-std\\=c++1z\\\""
```

In the generated Makefile I get:

```
DEFINES = -DCPP_COMPILER_SETTING=\"g++ \-std\=c++1z\"
```

I'm getting this error upon compilation:

```
g++: error: \-std\=c++1z": No such file or directory
```

How should I escape the string so that it makes it from the `.pro` file to the compiler's input?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have the following in the Makefile:

```
-DCPP_COMPILER_SETTING=\"g++\ -std=c++1z\"
                       ^^   ^           ^^
```

To take it to a `.pro` file, you need to escape backlashes and double quotes only. Thus, in the `.pro` file, you'll have:

```
DEFINES += "CPP_COMPILER_SETTING=\\\"g++\\ -std=c++1z\\\""
```

Test case:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << CPP_COMPILER_SETTING << std::endl;
}
```

When you google *qmake escaping defines with spaces*,  the [first result](http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/interest/2014-January/010804.html) is the correct solution.